# AppEngine section is missing

Tags: google-app-engine

my question is very simple. I created a new project in Google following these instructions: https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/getting-started

The issue is that on the console of this project, under Compute section, I don't have the AppEngine section (I have only Compute Engine). Here's a screenshot:

http://screencast.com/t/HwrFr9PDu

I can't find a way to create one...is there any way and why it's missing?

Comment: Have you deployed your app?

Comment: Hi Tx802, I've tried to deploy using Google App Engine Launcher, using the project name (which is corresponding to the App name in other projects) but it does not work,it says that the project does not exist. Note that I am able to deploy both via Laucher and via GIT to other projects, so my procedure is correct...

Comment: Does the app show up if you go to the old console at [appengine.google.com](http://appengine.google.com)?

Comment: nope. And even if I try to create a new app in there and I choose the same appid-projectid of my original project, it says that it's not available.

Comment: Perhaps there was a problem provisioning the cloud project.  Perhaps try creating a new project?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't easily create a new project. On this project's Storage, Google itself is loading the DBM (Doubleclick Bid Manager - a system used to deliver ad creatives, similar to an adserver) logfiles. I could request a change but that would mean waiting possibly weeks to have it updated and I would probably lose history (current files).

Comment: Hi Nikita. The project I'd is "progvisgroupm". I know that Google was looking at it already, internally, but then I told them to stop because I found a workaround to our issue. The issue is still there but it is not a problem for us anymore, as I can access those files from another project - unnecessarily complicated, but  working. A contact in Google told me it was probably an issue of "porting old projects to the new console"...

Comment: I removed my previous comment to hide email address. Have you tried to deploy with both s~appid and just appid in app.yaml?

Comment: The issue looks to be related to the project provisioning. Please let me know if you want me to open a support case based on the contact details for the project so we can investigate this further and try to fix it (it will take some time). Or do you prefer to leave it as it is as a workaround is available?

Comment: Hi Nikita. It's working fine now. Thanks for your offer but I prefer not to touch it, as our release is very close. Cheers!